# Comments in the stackexchange.com "activity" -> "comments" navigate to the post instead of the comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, stackexchange.com, network-profile, activity

My network wide comments are listed in the stackexchange.com ["activity" -> "comments"](https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar?tab=activity&sort=comments). When I'm clicking on any of the comment it navigates to the post instead of the particular comment.

But when I click the comment from site's ["activity" -> "comments"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312043/arulkumar?tab=activity&sort=comments), it navigates to the particular comment.

So will be the approach changed to navigate to the comment instead of post, in the stackexchange.com comments section too?